# Nullable bool logical "AND" operator behaves differently with true and false

Tags: c#, nullable, logical-operators

Using `bool?` variables, can somebody explain why `true & null` results in `null` and `false & null` results in `false`?

```
void Main()
{    
    bool? a = null;
    bool? b = true;
    bool? c = a & b;

    Console.WriteLine($"{b} & NULL => " + c);

    b = false;
    c = a & b;
    Console.WriteLine($"{b} & NULL => " + c);
}
```

Output:

> True & NULL => 
>   False & NULL => False

I would also be happy about the duplicate, because I did not find it, yet.

Comment: A guess: False and whatever can never be be true, but true & whatever can be true or false. But it's just a guess.

Comment: This is not a bitwise and... You're not operating on integers

Comment: @Adrian thank you, "This is not a bitwise" I did not know how to specify the it is only  one `&`. How to call it then ?

Comment: @MongZhu In C# we call `&` logical AND and `&&` conditional logical AND. Note that this only applies to `bool`. `&` is indeed the bitwise AND when applied to integers.

Comment: @Adrian cool, thanx for the detailed clarification and the edit. Cheers mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `null` in this is case is to identify an unknown value. In three-valued logic, the purpose of the `unknown` value is to indicate that we do not know anything about the truthy or the falsy of a predicate.

`false AND unknown` returns `false` because it is not important to know what the second operator is. This is due to the and operator nature that requires both the operands to be `true` to return `true`. As we know that the first operand is `false`, the rest is irrelevant, and the result is `false`.

On the other hand, `true AND unknown` returns `unknown`, because the first operand is `true`, and therefore the result of the whole operation depends on the second operand.  The second operand is `unknown`, therefore the result is `unknown`.

C# indicates `unknown` with `null`.

Comment: I mark this as accepted, because it has the most detailed explanation.

Comment: But it doesn't explain why `unknown & false` returns `false` and not `unknown`.

Comment: The AND operator returns true only when both of them are true. If at least one operand is false, the result is false. This is the definition of the AND operator. The fact that we are dealing with null here does not affect the outcome of this particular evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition (a & b), compiler just when find 1 false , returns false, else compare a and b, in his condition cant return real result, then returns nothing!

Answer (score 1):

Using nullable types means your booleans can actually have 3 values, `true`, `false` and `null`. This means you have to thing in terms of [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318788/null-values-boolean-expression) (which is for a sql question) covers the  results of `AND` and `OR` when using three-valued logic.

Comment: Ok, all right, but WHY ? Mong Zhu asked it why ?

Comment: Thanks for the links and the effort

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the bool? type has been designed to match a SQL Boolean, as described here
[Using nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types)
and quoted below

> The bool? type
>
> The bool? nullable type can contain three different values: true,
> false, and null. The bool? type is like the Boolean variable type that
> is used in SQL. To ensure that the results produced by the & and |
> operators are consistent with the three-valued Boolean type in SQL,
> the following predefined operators are provided: •bool? operator
> &(bool? x, bool? y) •bool? operator |(bool? x, bool? y)
>
> The semantics of these operators is defined by the following table:
>
> x y x&y x|y
>
> true true true true
> true false false true
> true null null true
> false true false true
> false false false false
> false null false null
> null true null true
> null false false null
> null null null null
>
> Note that these two operators don't follow the rules described in the
> Operators section: the result of an operator evaluation can be
> non-null even if one of the operands is null.

Comment: Ok, all right, but WHY ? Mong Zhu asked it why ?

Comment: Because. Probably because the SQL Boolean predated bool? and already had defined semantics